# Content won't align left with header tag against a div that floats left

Tags: html, css, styles, css-float, text-align

I am trying to add content to the right of an unordered list, but want it to be aligned left against the list (that is floated left). When I just add paragraphs and images, it works fine, but if I use header tags, it pushes all of the content to the bottom of the list.

See: http://www.advantly.com/guides/features/

The unordered list on the left is floating left

```
<div id="vertmenu" style="float: left;">
```

Style for the header tags in style.css are as follows:

```
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 { clear: both }
.clear { clear: both }
.clearfix:after {
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  content: ".";
  clear: both;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  height: 0;
}
```

Thank you to anyone who can offer help!

Comment: Off topic: style attributes should be avoided. It's better top have `#vertmenu { float: left; }` in your style sheet.

Comment: I guess you are editing this as we are looking at it. Currently, your left menu is just a div with no float: left. A div naturally is display: block, and will not allow another element to appear next to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a very basic example of how to float a couple of elements that live within a container element. Use this as a guide and you shouldn't go far wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/N3FPJ/

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
#vertmenu {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
}

#benefits-content {
    margin-right:210px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your headers css :

```
display: inline-block;
```

And this to your #commentsbox.

```
clear: both;
```

Comment: Thanks... just tried that but it didn't work. Also, the added code to the headers area seemed to mess up the display and spacing of the page & footer areas.

Answer (score 0):

Why don’t you just float the content left as well? Try adding this to the container of the content you want to the right:

```
float: left;
width: 600px;
```

Comment: thanks. I added
    `#benefits-content {
float:left;
width:600px;
}`

to the style sheet and placed my content in that div. This seemed to affect the content a little by pushing it down more, and it is aligned left, but below the features list. I need it to align left, but to the right of the unordered features list. I don't know if I'm making sense...

Comment: Yes you did, but you also removed the float on the menu, both of them should be floated to align next to each other.

Comment: I added the float to the style sheet instead, based on advice I received by another commenter above. So, they are both floating left.